# Chrome dev tools can't scroll all the way down

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I came across a strange thing in Chrome dev tools. In the network tab where I see my requests, I can't scroll all the way down, and I can't see the last 2 or 3 requests. What I did for a temporary fix was to replay the XHR from another request so the list will populate. Here is the what I mean:

[image]

Has anyone faced the same problem before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and found [this post on the google forums](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/Y7GmCWuUDGA/WUtOLFWAAAAJ). Clicking into the developer tools and hitting "CTRL+0" resolved this problem for me.

Comment: Godlike ! if you can explain why is this happening i'll make you a statue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but this solution isn't working for me. Do you have to click anywhere specific before pressing the keys? Also the link is dead for me.